# using zip and drop in Julia

Tags: functional-programming, iterator, julia

This code doesn't work for some reason:

```
collect(zip(drop([1,2,3], 1), drop([1,2,3], 1)))
```

I'm trying to drop the first element of a collection and zip up two copies of the result.

Comment: What version are you on? Works on 0.6 for me with some deprecation warnings about `drop` being replaced with `Iterators.drop`.

Comment: Also works on 0.5.

Comment: Can you check your `versioninfo()`? If you're not on v0.5+, you should really upgrade your Julia installation. The Julia version also shows itself at the top of each new REPL session.

Comment: Version 0.4.7 (2016-09-18 16:17 UTC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs perfectly fine for me. Please check your version using `versioninfo()`

```
julia> collect(zip(drop([1,2,3], 1), drop([1,2,3], 1)))
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (2,2)
 (3,3)

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.5.1
Commit 6445c82 (2017-03-05 13:25 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.7.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)

julia>
```